# variable template partial specialization and constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am trying to understand templates, and variable templates specifically. Consider this:

```
template<int M, int N>
const int gcd1 = gcd1<N, M % N>;

template<int M>
const int gcd1<M, 0> = M;

std::cout << gcd1<9, 6> << "\n";
```

It prints `0` which is wrong. However, if I use `constexpr` instead of `const` above, I get the proper answer `3`. I again get proper answer with structure template:

```
template<int M, int N>
struct gcd2 {
    static const int value = gcd2<N, M % N>::value;
};

template<int M>
struct gcd2<M, 0> {
    static const int value = M;
};
std::cout << gcd2<9, 6>::value << "\n";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
`gcd1` compiles fine without the base-case specialization also. How come? I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 (update 3)

Comment: GCC 6.3 gives the correct result with the first snippet. Could be Visual C++ thing.

Comment: @DeiDei, I don't have GCC compiler to try out. I hope someone confirms that it is indeed Visual C++ thing or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that it is a bug in *MSVC* compiler.

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/11/compiler-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-2/) page variable templates should be available since *MSVC 2015 update 2*. Seems that they do not work correctly even in *update 3*.

Anyway your code works fine with *gcc 6.1*: [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eAabz9LQI3t4Mo2Y)

Comment: Seems to be fixed in MSVC 2017 RC.